# Does the starting node matter for Breadth First Search and Depth First Search in order to visit all of the nodes?

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

For DFS and BFS should should we start at the root always in order to make sure we traverse all the nodes?

Comment: **DFS** and **BFS** are *graph*, not just *tree* traversals, so **no**, a *tree* is only a private case of a *graph* and graph traversal can start at an arbitrary node.

Answer (score 0):

No you can start on any node you like, but for each node the result can be different